# visual studio code python extension takes too much time to load pandas intellisense

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Vs Code editor python extension takes too much time to load pandas IntelliSense.

[image: Click here to see a sample image]

I don't know why. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? I mean is there any way to tweak or something to speed up the IntelliSense?

Sorry for my poor English

Thanks

Comment: use pycharm, it is much more suitable for python than VS or VS Code

Comment: How would VS know what is the type of the `movieDataset` to show the possible completions?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @ nickpick

Comment: I installed Gitlens plugin too after disabling it, its working fine again.